# parsley.js: issue with custom validator

Tags: parsley.js

I have a custom validator as shown below...

```
window.Parsley
  .addValidator('invalidwords', {
    requirementType: 'regexp',
    validateString: function(value, requirement) {
        var wordval = value.split(" ");
        $.each(wordval,function(idx,item) {
            return !/^\b(?:Stadium|GT|BB|HB|Simul|VNOSE|LT|combination|LT1|SSGT|BW|HBS|simul|combo|2hbs|4d|lt2|theatre)\b$/i.test(item)
        });
    },
    messages: {
      en: 'Invalid words detected.'
    }
  });
```

Basically what I want is to check a string to see if it contains any of the words in my regex.
Before I added the each() function it would work for single words, but it wouldn't work when i entered in something like `gt lt` so I had to put them in an array and check each one.
It appears to work when I debug as it does return false, but it seems as though parsley isn't seeing it or something to that effect.

Here is how I am calling it...

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="company" data-parsley-group="eventinfo" id="Company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" maxlength="60" tabindex="3" title="Company" parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-invalidwords="" value="#request.args.company#">
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried changing `requirementType: 'regexp',` to `requirementType: 'string',`

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. Had to do the return outside the loop. here is my final code.

```
window.Parsley
  .addValidator('invalidwords', {
    requirementType: 'regexp',
    validateString: function(value, requirement) {
        var wordval = value.split(" ");
        var valid = true;
        $.each(wordval,function(idx,item) {
            console.log(item,/^\b(?:Stadium|GT|BB|HB|Simul|VNOSE|LT|combination|LT1|SSGT|BW|HBS|simul|combo|2hbs|4d|lt2|theatre)\b$/i.test(item));
            if(/^\b(?:Stadium|GT|BB|HB|Simul|VNOSE|LT|combination|LT1|SSGT|BW|HBS|simul|combo|2hbs|4d|lt2|theatre)\b$/i.test($.trim(item))){
                valid = false;
            }
        });
        return valid;
    },
    messages: {
      en: 'Invalid words detected.'
    }
  });
```